# Why the GET request from Angular in the NodeJS sometimes come as null although there are data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mongoose

I am having sometimes a little problem with the `GET` request in `Angular`.
I am using `ReplaySubject` and return the `Observable` but sometimes in the reload of the app the `get` request it is working but it is getting `null` data or the message `No content` although there are the data.
In 3-4 tries then it shows the data.
The request `get` works but sometimes is null and sometimes give me the data.

Can someone help me on this ?
And if it possible to give any idea to use the `ReplaySubject` or something like, because i need to reload page everytime to fetch new data.

This is my `Frontend` part.

```
export class ModelDataService {
  public baseUrl = environment.backend;
  private data = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  public userID = this.authService.userID;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) {
  }

   public getJSON() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/data/${this.userID}`).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }

  public dataModel(): Observable<any> {
    return this.data.asObservable();
  }
  public setData(data: Model) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/data`;
    const user_id = this.authService.userID;
    this.http.post(api, data, {
      headers: {user_id}
    }).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }

  public updateDate(id: string, dataModel: Model) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/data/${id}`;
    return this.http.put(api, dataModel).subscribe(res => res);
  }
}
```

This is the `component` which I get data

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getUserProfile(this.userID).subscribe((res) => {
      this.currentUser = res.msg;
    });
    this.modelDataService.getJSON();
    this.model$ = this.modelDataService.dataModel();
    this.model$.subscribe((test) => {
      this.model = test;
    });
    this.model$.subscribe((test) => {
      this.model = test;
    });
  }
```

This is the `backend` part.

```
const ModelData = require("../models/data");

async show(req, res) {
let modelData;
await ModelData.findOne({user: req.params.id}, (error, user) => {
   modelData = user;
});
 if (!modelData) {
    res.status(204).json({error: "No Data"});
    return;
    }
return res.status(200).send(modelData);
},


routes.get("/data/:id", ModelDataController.show);
routes.post("/data", ModelDataController.store);
routes.put("/data/:id", ModelDataController.update);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass in a callback function, Mongoose will execute the query **asynchronously** and pass the results to the callback. Sometimes you don't get the data because the query is not finished excuting. To fix this, you can change your code to:

```
let modelData = await ModelData.findOne({user: req.params.id});
if (!modelData)...
```

Comment: that is working, but the same it is happening with `ReplaySubject` when I update something, it is updating the backend but I need to reload page to see the changes.
Do you have any idea  about it ?

Comment: Sorry. Im not familiar with `ReplaySubject`